# Output aggregated data to parquet using structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am playing with structured streaming using apache toree scala noteabook and would like to create a dataframe that summarizes (group by, count) my data and outputs the summaries to parquet files.
But all i see are empty files. Here is the relevant code from my notebook:

```
    val streamingCountsDF =   
         streamingInputDF
.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 week")
.dropDuplicates("timestamp","request")
.groupBy($"request",window($"timestamp", "1 hour"))
.count()
   streamingCountsDF.isStreaming


    val query =   streamingCountsDF
.writeStream
.format("parquet")        
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.second))
.option("path",parquetOutputPath)
.option("checkpointLocation","s3://mypath")    
.outputMode("append")    
.start()
```

Any ideas what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have skipped path.

```
 streamingCountsDF.writeStream
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerTime))
                .format("parquet")
                .option("checkpointLocation", s"$s3BaseUrl/check")
                .option("path", s3BaseUrl)
                .start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have path there.
As it turns our i see that it does work, just took a really long time to write out files. So i will close this issue